# YARD how to document @return type for a method that returns fixed-size array?

Tags: ruby, yard

I have the following method:

```rb
def foo
  [true_or_false, some_integer]
end
```

it always returns an array of 2 where 1st element is boolean and 2nd is integer.
How to document it in YARD using `@return` meta tag?

That's how it is later used:

```rb
is_success, exit_code = foo
```

I've checked the [official documentation on @return section](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#return) but it didn't help much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```rb
# @return [Array(Boolean, Number)] fixed-size array(vector) of a boolean followed by a number
def foo
  [true_or_false, some_integer]
end
```

---

Do not confuse it with other similar `@return` tag format:

```rb
# @return [Array<String, Symbol, #read>] an Array of (Strings, Symbols, objects that respond to #read)
```

which is for variable-length arrays of different data types, not for fixed-lenght vectors.